# Want to show page only when a submit button is clicked php

Tags: php, forms, session-variables

Hi friends am having 2 files index.php,form.php. In index.php I have given form action in index.php as form.php. How can I show the form.php when a button is clicked on index.php.But if the user types example.com/form.php in browser url its shown how can I hide it

Answer (score 1):

Set [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) and check if it is true then let `form.php` run else redirect on index page or you can merge your form only in one page

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

//if button clicked run this php

//your php code here...


} else { 
//if button not clicked show form
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" name="myform">

//form fields here...

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>

<?php } ?>
```

if button clicked it will execute php code else only form will be shown